# Artifactory cocoapods not found

Tags: cocoapods, artifactory

I’m setting up Artifactory cocoapods to be used in our Enterprise Fastlane builds in Jenkins. I set up 3 repositories: pods-local, pods-approved, and pods-remote. I deployed a simple internal pod to the pods-local repo. This worked fine until I added 3 more CocoaPods. None of these new CocoaPods could be found. I got this error: “Unable to find a specification for ”. Trying to fix it from info on the internet, I removed the repos from the Jenkins slave and started fresh. This is the command I used to remove the repos: “sudo rm -R  ~/.cocoapods/repos” and repos-art too. I reinstalled all the repos and now not even the simple internal pod can be found.

These are the errors I’m getting:
-   “repo is not a git repo.”
-   “Unable to find a specification for ”

I’ve looked online and have tried a number of fixes, with none working… including deleting and recreating the repos, pod setup, git reset --hard and more.

See the errors below.

Thanks for your help.

```
/Users/jenkinsci/.cocoapods/repos-art/pods-local/.artpodrc
/Users/jenkinsci/.cocoapods/repos-art/pods-local/.artpodrc
Updating local specs repositories
/Users/jenkinsci/.cocoapods/repos-art/pods-local/.artpodrc
fatal: Cannot change to '/Users/jenkinsci/.cocoapods/repos/pods-local': No such file or directory
[!] The `pods-local` repo is not a git repo.


[11:42:48]: [32mDriving the lane 'ios beta' [0m
[11:42:48]: [32m-----------------------[0m
[11:42:48]: [32m--- Step: cocoapods ---[0m
[11:42:48]: [32m-----------------------[0m
[11:42:48]: [4m[36m$ bundle exec pod install[0m[0m
[11:42:50]: ▸ [35m/Users/jenkinsci/.cocoapods/repos-art/pods-local/.artpodrc[0m
[11:42:50]: ▸ [35m/Users/jenkinsci/.cocoapods/repos-art/pods-local/.artpodrc[0m
[11:42:50]: ▸ [35mAnalyzing dependencies[0m
[11:42:50]: ▸ [35m/Users/jenkinsci/.cocoapods/repos-art/pods-local/.artpodrc[0m
[11:42:50]: ▸ [35m[!] Unable to find a specification for `APod`[0m
```

Comment: What error do you see in artifactory.log and the request.log in Artifactory?

Comment: There is not an error in the artifactory.log

Comment: Not the artifactory.log, the ** request.log ** of Artifactory.

Comment: The following was the request.log activity when I deployed an artifact to the pods-local repository in Artifactory:

Comment: 200|0
20170327095642|651|REQUEST|10.57.165.1|hzr1h5|PUT|/pods-local/GeminiCoreUI.tar.gz|HTTP/1.1|
201|1191863
20170327095647|118|REQUEST|10.58.167.187|hzr1h5|GET|/ui/systemlogs/logData|HTTP/1.1|